# Is "considered" Adjective?

Tags: adjectives, parts-of-speech

Is **considered** adjective in the below sentence? If it is adjective, why is it adjective?

> That could be **considered** 'best practice'.

Comment: No, it's a past participle verb used in a passive clause. It's clearly passive, as evident from the admissibilty of a _by_ phrase: "That could be considered best practice by xyz".

Comment: doesn't considered define the best practice ? @BillJ

Comment: "Best practice" is a noun phrase serving as direct object of "considered".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not in this context.

"Consider" is a verb. It means to think carefully about something. Some verbs can be used as adjectives in the past tense, for example:

> The toast was cold and burnt.

"Cold" is an adjective, because it is a property of the toast. "Burnt" is something that happened to the toast in the past, but it also *describes* the toast's condition now.

Likewise, "considered" *could* be used to describe a decision, for example:

> It was a carefully considered decision.

This is adding detail to the description of a decision that has already been made by describing it as having been carefully considered.

However, I do not think this is the case in your example.

> That could be considered 'best practice'.

"Best practice" usually refers to a framework of ideas or methods that are generally agreed as the best way of doing a job or task. In most fields, what actually constitutes "best practice" is subject to change, and not always strictly adhered to.

I read your example as saying that whatever preceded the statement could be thought of, or considered as being "best practice". It is encouraging you *to think* of it that way, and as such is an action, and a *verb*.

Comment: I didn't understand fully. Is 'considered' adjective or not ? @Astralbee

Comment: @MuratCanOĞUZHAN Astralbee told you that "consider" is a verb.

Comment: i know the consider is a verb but what is considered not consider

Comment: @MuratCanOĞUZHAN  "Considered" is here the past participle of the verb "consider".

Comment: as Passiv voice ? @BillJ

Comment: @MuratCanOĞUZHAN Yes: see my comment above.